# Contour plot using matlab fails

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour

I am trying to make a contour plot using the following matlab code:

```
x=linspace(-10,10);
y=linspace(-10,10);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=X.^3-Y.^3;
figure
[c,h]=contour(X,Y,Z,[3]);
clabel(c,h)
```

This gives me the wrong picture actually:
[image]

I really don't understand what goes wrong here, because when I do [c,h]=contour(X,Y,Z,[3 0]) for example, it does give me the correct contour plots for the levels 3 and 0, I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only give a single number to `contour` there, it interprets it as the number of contour lines you want and picks the levels automatically.  [From the docs](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html):

> contour(Z,v) draws a contour plot of matrix Z with contour lines at the data values specified in the monotonically increasing vector v. To display a single contour line at a particular value, define v as a two-element vector with both elements equal to the desired contour level. For example, to draw contour lines at level k, use contour(Z,[k k]). Specifying the vector v sets the LevelListMode property to manual.

e.g. to get a single contour at "3", you need to do it this way instead:

```
figure
[c,h]=contour(X,Y,Z,[3,3]);
clabel(c,h)
```

Answer (score 1):

The fourth argument of `contour` can be two things.

If it is an array of numbers (more than 1) then its the contour value you want to show. Else, if its a single value, its the **amount** of contour lines you want to show.

Example:

```
x=linspace(-10,10);
y=linspace(-10,10);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=X.^3-Y.^3;
figure
subplot(121)
[c,h]=contour(X,Y,Z,[10]);
clabel(c,h)
subplot(122)
[c,h]=contour(X,Y,Z,[1000 -1000 50 -70 3 0]);
clabel(c,h)
```

[image]